# Missing Copy/Debug traits warnings when defining enum with `strum` traits in macro

Tags: rust

I want to define an `enum` using a macro. The `enum` needs to implement the `strum` traits `{Display, EnumIter, EnumString}`. I also want to keep the warnings `missing_copy_implementations, missing_debug_implementations` on. I came up with the following snippet:

```rust
#![warn(
    missing_copy_implementations,
    missing_debug_implementations,
)]

macro_rules! define_fruits {
    {$($fruit:ident -> $name:literal),* $(,)?} => {
        #[derive(Display, EnumIter, EnumString, Clone, Copy, Debug)]
        pub enum Fruits {
            $(
                #[strum(to_string = $name)]
                $fruit,
            )*
        }
    };
}

define_fruits! {
    Apple -> "green",
    Orange -> "orange",
}
```

The above works fine except I get the warnings:

```
   |
4  |     missing_copy_implementations,
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: this warning originates in the macro `define_fruits` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

and similar for `missing_debug_implementations`.

These warnings go away when I remove `Display, EnumIter, EnumString` from my `enum`. They also go away if I define the same `enum` outside of a macro.

I cannot seem to find a way to get rid of the warnings in the above scenario, can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL/DR: the problem is with `derive(EnumIter)`, which isn't compatible with these lints. I've opened [the issue on `strum` repository](https://github.com/Peternator7/strum/issues/229) asking for possible changes.

---

To see what really happens, let's try to [`cargo expand`](https://github.com/dtolnay/cargo-expand) the current code. After some simplification and stubbing out the unnecessary parts, we can see the following structure:

```
///An iterator over the variants of [Self]
pub struct FruitsIter {
    idx: usize,
    back_idx: usize,
    marker: PhantomData<()>,
}
```

This is a type you get when you call [`IntoEnumIterator::iter`](https://docs.rs/strum/latest/strum/trait.IntoEnumIterator.html#tymethod.iter) derived for your enum. There's no `Copy` or `Debug` implementation for this struct - they are neither derived nor explicitly added by `strum`, so the lint sees the violation and fires.

A hint on the problem source can be seen when looking at the exact error, as provided by `cargo check` (or at the eror highlighting from `rust-analyzer`):

```
warning: type could implement `Copy`; consider adding `impl Copy`
  --> src/lib.rs:10:27
   |
10 |           #[derive(Display, EnumIter, EnumString, Clone, Copy, Debug)]
   |  ___________________________^
11 | |         pub enum Fruits {
   | |___________^
```

Note that the span of the "erroneous" code starts from the `EnumIter` - since that's the token which the `FruitsIter`'s span is tied to, warning on the `FruitsIter` is shown as a warning on the `derive(EnumIter)`. And indeed, if we drop this derive - warning disappears.

There's nothing you can do with this, I'm afraid, aside from explicitly `allow`ing these lints for the whole module containing your enum. This is something that should probably be fixed by the `strum` maintainers.